# mariaDB install in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: mariadb, ubuntu-16.04

i was install mariaDB 10.1 in Ubuntu16.04LTS

i use this code.

`sudo apt-get install mariadb-server`

install is success, but when i connect to mariadb, it is don't need password!

i was try this. but these all doesn't work.

1. i use `mysql_secure_installation` command and finish configuration successfully. but it is still don't need password.
2. `SET PASSWORD FOR 'root'@'%' = PASSWORD('newpass');` and `flush privilege`
3. update user set password=password('newpass') where user='root';

i want use password. what should i do?

Comment: `SELECT user, host, password FROM mysql.user;` -- may give clue of what is wrong.

Comment: Looks like this is the same issue as this one: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30417831/6451083
MariaDB 10.0.17 cannot access root with non-root user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My answer to "i want use password. what should i do?" is:

**"no, you probably don't!"** (depending on your app's deployment - see comments below)

With Ubuntu 15.10 and later MariaDB installs with the unix_socket user authentication plugin enabled by default: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/unix_socket-authentication-plugin/

With a fresh install login with `sudo mysql -uroot` and execute:

```
SELECT User, Password, Host, plugin from mysql.user WHERE user = 'root';
```

You should see a single user. This also means you cannot remotely login as root with the default install (one of the tasks the `mysql_secure_installation` performs).

```
+------+----------+-----------+-------------+
| User | Password | Host      | plugin      |
+------+----------+-----------+-------------+
| root |          | localhost | unix_socket |
+------+----------+-----------+-------------+
```

I would recommend leaving this as-is and creating a non-root user with the appropriate permissions for your application to use.

However, if you **absolutely need** a password-authenticated root user you need to change the plugin to `mysql_native_password`.

```
UPDATE mysql.user SET plugin = 'mysql_native_password', Password = PASSWORD('secret') WHERE User = 'root';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Now `quit` then log-in with `mysql -uroot -p`.

Note if you need to restart the service you will need to do three commands instead of just `sudo systemctl restart mysql`. I am pretty sure there is some addition to a `.cnf` file you can make so that restart will work as expected but I couldn't easily figure it out. Basically the lesson is use `unix_socket`.

```
sudo systemctl stop mysql
sudo kill -9 $(pgrep mysql)
sudo systemctl start mysql
```

Comment: Note that attempting to use the unix socket authentication breaks a number of applications with SSH tunneling.  It may actually, still, be a better idea overall to use mysql native password authentication just so you can bury the entire server behind a firewall and tunnel into it.

Comment: Good point @damianb. I guess it depends on what application deployment (above is perfect for co-located Wordpress, Nextcloud etc).